# How to export/get the Alerting Rules from prometheus using Python

Tags: python, devops, prometheus, monitoring

We have more than 200 alerts created on prometheus. I want to somehow get/export them one by one to a txt file. I want to automate that.
Can you recommend me any way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

[Alerting rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) are generally defined in YAML files that are passed to Prometheus through configuration.

So, if you own (can access) the Prometheus servers, you should be able to grab the rules YAML configs from them directly.

You can query a Prometheus server for its rules through its API endpoint.

For example for a Promethues server on `localhost:9090`, querying `http://localhost:9090/api/v1/rules` will return a JSON-formatted list of the server's rules.

It should be straighforward to make such HTTP requests against any number of Prometheus servers using Python and unmarshalling the resulting JSON into whatever format that you need.

Comment: I'm pleased that it helped.

Comment: Using the API, do you have any idea how we could export some of the alerts triggered in prometheus within a specific period of time to excel? I have tried using python but it doesn't work for me.....

Comment: @emmanuel-spencer-egbuniwe Please ask questions as a question rather than as a comment. I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78070937/609290) your question on a similar question without response